# Depth map multithreading

Tags: multithreading, python-3.6, opencv3.0

I am trying to make my depth map video faster and so I ended up to multithreading.
I am having difficulties to understand this topic as I don't succeed to find an example enough clear for me.

Imagining a simple code as :

```
img1= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img2= cv2.VideoCapture(1)
stereo= cv2.StereoSGBM.compute(img1,img2)
```

Comment: What's the question now?

Comment: having 2 cameras and a stereo image, how do i set multithreading?

Comment: i don't ask for a code, but even a guideline about which direction follow would be helpful